# Timedelta calculation showing biggest ranges pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

Hi Guys i need to calculate delta between 2 `datetime64[ns]`

However this are returning to me a biggest delta, thata is visible unreal.
I donr understanding the reson why this error are happening, because both dates have the same format.

```
df1=
              entrada      First_Time_log
0    2020-06-09 01:50:00 2020-06-09 03:13:22
1    2020-06-10 01:50:00 2020-06-10 02:31:31
2    2020-06-11 01:50:00 2020-06-11 02:00:07
3    2020-06-12 01:50:00 2020-06-12 03:39:59
4    2020-06-13 01:50:00 2020-06-13 04:05:28
...                  ...                 ...
4255 2020-06-02 01:50:00 2020-06-02 02:00:02
4256 2020-06-03 01:50:00 2020-06-03 02:09:16
4257 2020-06-04 01:50:00 2020-06-04 01:20:14
4258 2020-06-05 01:50:00 2020-06-05 01:11:39
4259 2020-06-06 01:50:00 2020-06-06 01:35:11
```

But after apply operation below:

```
dfc['entrada-first'] = dfc['entrada'] -  dfc['First_Time_log']
```

It returns biggest range, so the range bitwenn dates is less then 24 hours.
What i doing wrong?

```
               entrada      First_Time_log     entrada-first
0    2020-06-09 01:50:00 2020-06-09 03:13:22 -1 days +22:36:38
1    2020-06-10 01:50:00 2020-06-10 02:31:31 -1 days +23:18:29
2    2020-06-11 01:50:00 2020-06-11 02:00:07 -1 days +23:49:53
3    2020-06-12 01:50:00 2020-06-12 03:39:59 -1 days +22:10:01
4    2020-06-13 01:50:00 2020-06-13 04:05:28 -1 days +21:44:32
...                  ...                 ...               ...
4255 2020-06-02 01:50:00 2020-06-02 02:00:02 -1 days +23:49:58
4256 2020-06-03 01:50:00 2020-06-03 02:09:16 -1 days +23:40:44
4257 2020-06-04 01:50:00 2020-06-04 01:20:14          00:29:46
4258 2020-06-05 01:50:00 2020-06-05 01:11:39          00:38:21
4259 2020-06-06 01:50:00 2020-06-06 01:35:11          00:14:49
```

Comment: try calculating `dfc['entrada-first'] = dfc['First_Time_log'] - dfc['entrada'] `

Comment: Its returns negative for values that are being positive in the first mode.

Comment: You can try my updated solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you want the absolute value of the timedelta? E.g.

```
import pandas as pd
# example df:
df = pd.DataFrame({'entrada': pd.to_datetime(['2020-06-03 01:50:00','2020-06-04 01:50:00']),
                   'First_Time_log': pd.to_datetime(['2020-06-03 02:09:16','2020-06-04 01:20:14'])})
# Python's built-in abs works fine here:
df['td_abs'] = abs(df['entrada']-df['First_Time_log'])
# df['td_abs']
# 0   00:19:16
# 1   00:29:46
# Name: td_abs, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calculating the time difference as follows:

[image]

```
def find_time_difference(x):
    if x["entrada"] >= x["First_Time_log"]:
        return x["entrada"] - x["First_Time_log"]
    elif x["entrada"] <= x["First_Time_log"]:
        return x["First_Time_log"] - x["entrada"]
    return ''
df["entrada-first"] = df.apply(lambda x: find_time_difference(x), axis=1)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: why the complicated function? you could just take the absolute of the timedelta

Comment: @MrFuppes, Yes it would have been better.